# is strings in .net get changed?? is there some bug?

Tags: .net, string, pointers, unsafe

I have written a function Reverse to reverse a string in .net using pointers in unsafe context.
I do like this.

I allocate “greet” and “x” same value. 
I reverse greet to my surprise x also gets reversed.

```
using System;

class Test{

    private unsafe static void Reverse(string text){
        fixed(char* pStr = text){
            char* pBegin = pStr;
            char* pEnd = pStr + text.Length - 1;
            while(pBegin < pEnd){
                char t = *pBegin;
                *pBegin++ = *pEnd;
                *pEnd-- = t; 
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Main(){
        string greet = "Hello World";
        string x = "Hello World";
        Reverse(greet);
        Console.WriteLine(greet);
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: I hope you have really good reason for using pointers in C# ...

Comment: @jrummell was trying to get max perfromance...

Comment: Unless you've benchmarked your app and confirmed that this piece of code is "slow", don't bother with this kind of optimization.

Comment: @jrummell last resort, hope not required!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nothing odd about that. You're seeing *interning*. If you write:

```
Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(greet, x));
```

immediately after the declaration, you'll see that you've only got *one string object*. Both your variables refer to the same object, so obviously if you make a modification to the object via one variable, you'll see the same change when you access it later through the other variable.

From the C# 4 spec, section 2.4.4.5:

> Each string literal does not necessarily result in a new string instance. When two or more string literals that are equivalent according to the string equality operator appear in the same program, these string literals refer to the same string instance.

Oh, and I hope that in real code you're not *actually* modifying strings using unsafe operations...

Comment: but i created 2 instances.. strange.

Comment: @Pritesh: No you didn't. You declared two variables, and used the same string literal for both, which means you have two variables which both refer to the same string object.

Comment: @Pritesh: No, I've shown that it's specified behaviour. The "glitch" is you modifying string objects, which are normally assumed to be immutable.

Comment: was trying conme up our own "stringbuilder" kind of class.. seems need to think solution in safe context... I was wondering if string are immutable how .net compiler/run time allowed me to modify it???